# Compile error with MWE using pgfkeys, beamer, xparse and \includegraphics

Tags: beamer, graphics, pgfkeys, xparse

First, please apologize the vague title, but I do not understand the problem enough to give a more exact title.

The following MWE does not compile with a `missing \endcsname inserted` error around `\linewidth` with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pgfkeys{
    /tikzscale/.is family, /tikzscale,
    width/.code = {\the#1},
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}}{%
% \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1][]{%
        \pgfkeys{/tikzscale, #1}%
}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
    text
\end{document}
```

If either of both commented lines is uncommented (while commenting the line above), the file compiles, i.e. the combination of `pgfkeys`, `beamer`, `xparse` and `\includegraphics` seems to trigger the error.  [Putting `\AtBeginDocument` around the redefinition of `\includegraphics`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67434/redefine-includegraphics-for-beamer) does also solve the problem.

Why doesn't this combination work? What is the difference between `\RenewDocumentCommand` and `\renewcommand` in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `beamer` redefines `\includegraphics` at begin document in terms of the meaning it had at that moment.

With `\renewcommand` things seem to go straight, but with `\RenewDocumentCommand` there's a different scanning mechanism for optional arguments and chaos ensues.

I wouldn't mix the two ways. In any case, redefining commands declared robust (as `beamer` does with `\includegraphics`) can be *very* risky.

Comment: Is there any way how to detect this different scanning mechanism or to see that a robust command is redefined? I think about interpreting `\meaning\includegraphics` or something like that. Reading `beamer`'s source could also be an option, but if possible I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @MMM Say `\tracingmacros=1` before the command to be tested and this will give plenty of information in the log file